# how to convert datatable to list and use that list as datasource to datagrid vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have Datatable that has many rows, what I need is to convert this Datatable to a list to use it as data source for Datagrid, I know that I can use the Datatable as data source but I don't want that because I have a lot of rows so using the Datatable make the Datagrid so slow so I need to inject the Datagrid with a list.
I found the following code but I couldn't apply it because it uses a name to the Datatable.

```
public void StudentList()  
{  

    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Student");  
    dt.Columns.Add("StudentId", typeof(Int32));  
    dt.Columns.Add("StudentName", typeof(string));  
    dt.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));  
    dt.Columns.Add("MobileNo", typeof(string));  
    //Data  
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "Manish", "Hyderabad", "0000000000");  
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Venkat", "Hyderabad", "111111111");  
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Namit", "Pune", "1222222222");  
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "Abhinav", "Bhagalpur", "3333333333");  
  
    List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();  
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)  
    {  
        Student student = new Student();  
        student.StudentId = Convert .ToInt32 (dt.Rows[i]["StudentId"]);  
        student.StudentName = dt.Rows[i]["StudentName"].ToString();  
        student.Address = dt.Rows[i]["Address"].ToString();  
        student.MobileNo = dt.Rows[i]["MobileNo"].ToString();  
        studentList.Add(student);  
    }  
}
```

see that the Datatable has named as "DataTable dt = new DataTable("Student")"

but my Datatable has no name, it's just "dim xDt as new Datatable"
and the code is "C#" but I need "Vb.Net", I tried to convert it but I couldn't.

my second question is: is there any way to use the fast Datasource to Datagrid?

Comment: For the list you can ignore the DataTable-Name. That's just important if the DataTable is part of a DataSet. But in general its not clear to me why you think that the list makes a big difference here. Why you fill a DataTable in the first place? It sounds like you are simply loading too many rows, use paging.

Comment: that's what I mean, I need some ideas to load big data , how to make the paging?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I load too many rows but the problem is even I have few rows the Datagrid is slow because I have many combo boxes columns inside the Datagrid.

Comment: Perhaps a better idea might be to go back a couple steps.  Why even load it into a DataTable at all, load your data directly into a List(of StudentClass).  Depends of course on what exactly is the data source.  That aside, completely agree with @TimSchmelter.  There really shouldn't be any perceivable difference between a list and a datatable, you could "almost" say a DataTable is a List(of DataRow).

Comment: As for converting C# -> vb.net.  My opinion is unfortunately now as most examples and tutorials seem C# based, that us a skill you need to master.  There are many online tools that will do the conversion for you with varying levels of success, as well as a tag on this sit specifically for help with C# -> vb.net conversions